# GitFlow with TFS 2013, bumping versions

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, gitflow, nuget

We have TFS 2013 only for version control, Team City for building, a Nuget server and Visual Studio 2013.  Little late in the game but we haven't set guidelines for getting code from development into a build and package management process.  Git-Flow as shown below will work for most of our projects (i.e. we need only one development line).  We aren't forced into TFS but I would like to see if GitFlow can work even with TFS (**note**: not much prior experience with TFS instead Git).  With TFS 2013+ merging a branch like **release** below should be possible into **master**?  There was a restriction (I think) with pre-2013 TFS that branch merging was only possible back to it's origin (i.e. **development** in the **release** case).

We should be able to let TeamCity drive Nuget package management when a version (**note**: a semantic version, http://semver.org/) changes (i.e. the round bubbles on the **master** and **development** lines).  Anybody done this?

When working on a **feature**, **release** or **hotfix** branch it is the responsibility of the development team to set the correct version in the assembly.  Only *we* can know if there is a major, minor or patch change.  Thus only *we* can update the assembly information.  That said when code is checked into either the **master** or **development** TFS will automatically up the change set (I think per collection).  To handle merges into **development** or **master** that demand a new version do people with TFS use pull requests (if they have update 4 or is this only if the code is managed by Git)?  Otherwise, there is a risk that version numbers won't get set correctly.

My main question is really how people handle bumping versions in TFS and a builder like Team City to later on pump out a NuGet package?  With a bunch of over administration?

[image: GitFlow]